# Need help in designing a regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

```
"LIM-1-2::PROVPEC=NTK552DA,CTYPE=\"LIM C-Band\":OOS-AU,UEQ"   
"2XOSC-1-4::PROVPEC=NTK554BA,CTYPE=\"OSC w/WSC 2 Port SFP 2 Port 10/100 BT\":OOS-AU,UEQ"
"P155M-1-4-1::PROVPEC=NTK592NP,CTYPE=\"OC-3 0-15dB CWDM 1511 nm\":OOS-AU,UEQ"
```

I have this data in a file. I need to extract -1-2 for first equipment likewise -1-4-1 for last one. I will using this data later. I am able to figure out how to get -1-1 but it's not versatile enough to get -1-1-4 also.

Equipment can also have a subslot.This list is tentative.
EQP-shelf-slot-subslot. I need some expression which can check if subslot exists or not  provides me out in form -shelf-slot-subslot or -shelf-slot

Comment: Not sure I'd even bother with regex here, just split on the first `::` and then split again on the first `-`.

Comment: Could you please post what you have so far?

Comment: @David Parsson      ($commandline=~/\".*(-.-.).*PROVPEC=(.*?),/)

Comment: Thankyou. I will try splitting it. I just started working with work.
@AlexHowansky

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
my ($wanted) = $str =~  /^\w+([^:]+)/;
```

or, if quotes are part of the string:

```
my ($wanted) = $str =~  /^"\w+([^:]+)/;
```

Comment: `"` is are part file content I guess.

Comment: It appears that the double quotes are part of the OP's data, so `/"\w+([^:]+)/` may be a better match.

Comment: @Kenosis it doesnt give me any output 
my $String="LIM-1-1::PROVPEC=NTK552DA,CTYPE=";


my $String1="ENT-EQPT::P155M-1-4-1:P155M1::NTK592NP::IS";

if($String=/"\w+([^:]+)/)   {

  
print "AID=$1 \n ";
}

Comment: @Kenosis
my $commandline="LIM-1-1::PROVPEC=NTK552DA,CTYPE=";


my $String1="ENT-EQPT::P155M-1-4-1:P155M1::NTK592NP::IS";
 
 
 
 if( $String1 =~ /^"\w+([^:]+)/){

  
print "AID=$1 \n ";
}

Comment: @Kenosis
it doesnt give me output. 
my $commandline="LIM-1-1::PROVPEC=NTK552DA,CTYPE=";


my $String1="ENT-EQPT::P155M-1-4-1:P155M1::NTK592NP::IS";
 
 
 
 if( $String1 =~ /^"\w+([^:]+)/){

  
print "AID=$1 \n ";
}